# Assign json data as button ID

Tags: jquery, html

I'm loading json data via the below code in to a table. I'm having problems adding the button (shown as `var edBtn`) and assigning `item.id`(retrieved data) as its ID.

```
$.getJSON('php/um_getallusers.php',function(dta){
      var $tbody = $("#um tbody").empty();
      $.each(dta, function(index, item) {
          var edBtn = $('<button />', { class: 'btn btn-info btn-xs', text: 'Col', type: 'button' });
          $tr = $("<tr/>").appendTo($tbody);
          $('<td/>').text(item.id).appendTo($tr);
          $('<td/>').text(item.name).appendTo($tr);
          $('<td/>').text(item.username).appendTo($tr);

          $('<td/>').edBtn.appendTo($tr);
      });
});
```

**EDIT:**

JSON response:

```
[
  {
    "id":"2","0":"2","name":"Marie Leem","1":"Marie Leem","username":"xtyz","2":"xtyz"
  },
  {
    "id":"1","0":"1","name":"John Doah","1":"John Doah","username":"doahM","2":"doahM"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this, it looks like you want to add button in td:

```
 var $td = $('<td/>', { id: item.id});
 edBtn.appendTo($td);
 $td.appendTo($tr);
```

See [**DEMO EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/so5oykwc/), in demo i have used button, you can do same on `td`

Comment: thanks. I tried that now but did not solve the issue. Not sowing a button also it's showing only the first row of data in the table.

Comment: Did not work. Does not show any data in the table now.

Comment: thanks. got it working. Is it possible to assign a retrived value (json) as its id?

Comment: Appreciate your help. :)